# Convert date format in MySQL column with Update query

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-update, date-formatting

I am importing a CSV file I download from a website to display to clients in my PHP App. The date the website spits out in the CSV is not MySQL friendly. I want to convert it in the table immediately after importing the CSV file. The date in the CSV file is this format: **February 06 2023 08:26:44**

I'm running the following query:

```
update tblname set `time` = STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') where `time` = STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

This is the error I get in phpmyadmin:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1292 - Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'February 06 2023 08:26:44'

Due to the nature of the log, I need the time to be kept as well. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You tell that "The date in the CSV file" - but use UPDATE which means that this date is already imported (incorrectly imported!) into the table. So we'd know all details of this skipped step.

Comment: You can't change the format of a `DATETIME` column. You do formatting when retrieving dates, not when storing them.

Comment: *set `time` = STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')* - This doesn't make sense to me.  You're trying to update the `time` column to a formatted/parsed version of... itself?  Was this "February 06 2023 08:26:44" value already imported into the DB?  What is the type of the `time` column?  What value does it contain when executing this query?

Comment: If the column is `DATETIME` datatype, you have to call `STR_TO_DATE()` when importing from the CSV.

Comment: Hi David. The CSV file has the date as 'February 06 2023 08:26:4'. The column currently has a VARCHAR value. It's a huge log that I'm importing and need to query later based on event time.

Comment: @Ronaldo: It sounds like the CSV is irrelevant at this point.  What you have is a `VARCHAR` column which contains a string that intuitively (but not technically) represents date information, and you want to re-write what's in that column.  Ideally this column *should* be `DATETIME` since it's storing... a date-time value.  And the formatting step should be part of the import process, not afterward.  Because even after you format it, you still just have a `VARCHAR` and not a `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE(time, '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s')` parses the formatted date and returns the date that you want to store in the table:

```
UPDATE tblname 
SET `time` = STR_TO_DATE(`time`, '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

The `WHERE` clause is not needed.